# How do I go inside the locked building in Snowdin?

Tags: undertale

Is there a way to enter the locked building beside Sans' and Papyrus' house in Snowdin? If yes, how so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes**. If you are defeated by Papyrus, instead of seeing a "Game Over" screen, Papyrus will "capture" you, and lock you in the guest room. Don't worry though, he gives you a nice bed and some food.

It's not actually locked, though, and the bars are too wide to stop you from leaving.

[image: Papyrus' guest room]

There is no other way to enter this building.